# Using Java Script or jquery regex to verify if a string contains another string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am building a simple search where query string can have wild cards '*'. Search terms can be like following:

- animal
- ani*
- *mal
- an*al

all above should return true if the word is 'animal'.

how this can be done in JS / jquery?

will appreciate for help.
rnv

Comment: Replace `*` by `.*` before applying regex

Comment: use regular expressions for that

Comment: I guess you are looking for `\w*`, else `.*` will match even `any animal` with `an*al`, and you say you need to match 1 word. The problem here is with Unicode letters. Do you need to also support Unicode?

Comment: You're asking about regular expressions, but I think the heart of your question is really about [Approximate string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching). Is that true?

Comment: Yes. but can you give me hint how to use approximate string matching using jquery or js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The match on a string is simple:

```
var mystring = "This is my string";
var myregex = /*some regex*/
var results = mystring.match(myregex); // you can also write the regex directly as the argument of the match method, without using any variable.
```

So in your case you could have:

```
var mystring = "animal";
var myregex = new RegExp(inputQuery.replace(/\*/g, '.*'), 'gi'); // gi stands for 'global' and 'ignorecase' when applying the regex
var results = mystring.match(myregex);
```

Beware that `.*` matches zero or more (comes from the `*` whildcard) character, ANY character (comes from the `.`)
If you want to match zero or more letter, number or underscoreuse `\w*`, if you want to match one or more, use `\w+`, and if you want to match a specific number of letters, use `\w{x}` (`\w{3}` matches exactly 3 letters).

Comment: replace('*', '.*') replaces only one instance of '*'. is there a way to replace all instances? query can be 'a*im*l'

Comment: @user1749707 `string.replace(searchvalue,newvalue)` actually does replace **ALL** instances of the `searchvalue` with `newvalue`. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)'s the docs.

Comment: @user1749707 I updated the answer. I forgot to mention that you should use a regex with the global flag set, in order to replace ALL occurrences of a string, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "anim*";
var replaced = str.replace("*", ".*");
var regex = new RegExp(replaced);
var result = regex.test("animal");
console.log(result);
```

change the `str` variable to get the result as true or false;

Comment: Thanks works fine but if the query string contains multiple '*' then it failes. e.g. str='an*m*l'.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented version - https://jsfiddle.net/dpoqnacv/1/

```
var regexString = '^'+ $('#searchbox').val().replace("*",".*") + '$';

    if(new RegExp(regexString).test('animal'))
          $('#resultdiv').html('Matching...');
    else
        $('#resultdiv').html('Not Matching...');
```

Comment: you may need to do a global replace of * if you are going to have multiple wildcards in the search.

Answer (score 0):

You can just transform your wildcard into a RegExp and perform your search. Here is a simple example.

```js
var search = document.getElementById("search");
var result = document.getElementById("result");


result.style.color = "red";

function fsearch() {
    var str=search.value;
    str = str.replace("*", ".*") //Transform your wildcard into a RegExp
    result.innerHTML = "animal".match(new RegExp(str));
}
```

```html
<label for="search">Search : <input name="search" id="search" type="text"/></label>
<input id="ok" type="button" value="ok" onclick="fsearch()"/>
Result : <div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

not bad answers but i think its easier with .test();

```
var str = "my dog is an animal";

/dog*anim*/.test(str); //returns true
/d*mal/.test(str); //returns true
```

etc

give it a try